# Help Constructing an infinitely differentiable function...

Tags: real-analysis

Given $a<b$, I need to find a function $\psi\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ so that $\psi(x)=0$ when $x\leq a$, $0<\psi(x)<1$ when $a<x<b$, and $\psi(x)=1$ when $x\geq b$.

Previously, I had found a function $\varphi\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying, $\varphi(x)=0$ when $x\not\in (a,b)$ and $\varphi(x)>0$ when $x\in(a,b)$. I was given the hint that I should try $\psi(x)=c \int^x_{-\infty} \varphi $ with $c$ being a constant I should determine. I defined 
$$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{M(b-a)} \int^x_{-\infty} \varphi $$ 
where $M$ is the maximum of $\varphi$ on $[a,b]$, which is positive by the qualities of $\varphi$ and is obtained on the interval by the EVT. This $\psi$ satisfies the first two needed specifications, but I am having a hard showing the last one is satisfied. As defined I don't think the last is upheld. Any suggestions on how to modify $\psi$ so it works? Is it possible (in a nice way) to make this $\psi$ piecewise and still infinitely differentiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $M=\int_{[a,b]}\phi(x)dx$ and remove the $(b-a)$ from denominator.

Comment: thanks, that worked nicely!